# Mysql JDBC resultset.deleteRow not working

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the following problem:

Can not delete a table row using the resultset `deleteRow` function. My code is like this:

```
con = SqlService.getConnection(DB.NIPO_GBS_HIGHWAY);    
String sqlQuery = "select vehicle,vehicle_nipo_id from vehicles where vehicle = ?";
pstm = con.prepareStatement(sqlQuery, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
pstm.setString(1, scaleId);
rs = pstm.executeQuery();
if(rs.next())
{
   if(nipoId.isEmpty())
    {
        rs.deleteRow();
    }
    else
    {
       rs.updateString(2, nipoId);
       rs.updateRow(); 
    }      
    sqlQueryResult = SqlQueryResult.SQL_SUCCESS;
}
else
{ 

}
```

The code executes without throwing an exception but when i check the database i see that the row is not deleted.

Any reason for this? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Try to add some debugging statements.Have u `try` `catch` then in the catch use e.printStackTrace().

Comment: The code executes without throwing an exception

Comment: try to execute the query `delete from table where id=someValue`

Comment: this is an alternative solution! Does not give a reason why it doesnt work the way i want

Comment: Can u post the method in which these statements are ?

Comment: Is your connection readonly?

Comment: I can update a row. Just can not delete it!

Comment: see this post may it is helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104882/java-delete-a-selected-row-resultset-deletes-last-row-from-the-database-instea

Comment: "The code executes without throwing an exception" doesn't mean it's correct. Are you sure `rs.deleteRow()` is ever executed i.e. is `nipoId.isEmpty()` ever `true`? Also, your top-most `else` block is empty. You might want to put a log statement there to detect when it's reached.

Answer (score 0):

What about commiting changes and closing ?