# Logical error when trying to remove an item from a JList

Tags: java, mysql, data-access-layer

I have a JList that shows all the items I have added to the database. When I want to remove multiple items, say two items, just one of them gets removed. This is my code: 
This method is from my class DAL:

```
public void removeStudent(Student student)throws SQLException{
  PreparedStatement studentStatement = getConnected().prepareStatement(
    "delete from student where spnr = ? and sname = ? and sadress = ? " +
     " and stel = ? ");

  studentStatement.setString(1, student.getIdNumber());
  studentStatement.setString(2, student.getName());
  studentStatement.setString(3, student.getAddress());
  studentStatement.setString(4, student.getTel());
  studentStatement.executeUpdate();
}
```

The class Controller:

```
public void removeStudent(Student student) throws SQLException{
  dal.removeStudent(student);
}
```

and the class View. Used in the actionListener when the button remove is clicked.

```
private void removeStudent(){
  try{
    controller.getDal().getStudentData().getName();
    controller.getDal().getStudentData().getAddress();
    controller.getDal().getStudentData().getIdNumber();   
    controller.getDal().getStudentData().getTel();

    controller.removeStudent(controller.getDal().getStudentData());
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

And the ActionEvent

```
if(infLst.getSelectedIndex() > -1){
  int choice = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
                 "Delete?" + "The student will be permamently deleted",
                 null,
                 JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
  if(choice == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    //Removes from the JList            
    ((DefaultListModel)infLst.getModel()).removeElementAt(index);
    //And database 
    removeStudent();
  }else{
    return;
  }
}else{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure you have selected an item from the list");
}
}}});
```

Please consider that I'm new in this field with database programming. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> When I want to remove multiple items, say two items, just one of them gets removed.

Your code only has an if condition that checks the selected index so it will only ever delete one item.

If you want to delete all selected values then you need to use a method from JList that returns multiple values to delete. Look at the API for other `getSelected...()` methods that you can use for this purpose. Then you will need to create a loop to delete all the values.

The method that return Objects istead of index values will be easier to use since you can just delete the Object from the model and you don't need to worry about deleting the higher indexed value first.

Comment: I use a Single interval selection. I don't really want to select three items to delete. I want to delete three items once a time. Example: Select item 1 --> Delete, Select item 2 --> delete and so on.

Comment: The problem isn't the list. Both of the items gets deleted from the list, the problem is the database where the item still is there even if i have deleted it from the JList

Comment: @Eskipo,  Your SQL statement has a "where clause" so only records that match that criteria are deleted. Since you are only removing one item from the JList it also makes sense that only one row is deleted from your database table. That is every student will have a unique id number. If fact you don't even need all the other data in the where statement to delete the student, the id number should be sufficient.

Comment: okay but should the SQL statement look different? Maybe delete * from student? Should this solve the problem?

Comment: the thing is that when I test the program in command line I can delete both of the items from the database. This problem occurs when I use a JList.

Comment: I really need help. I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: A JList has nothing to do with SQL. You need to verify that your SQL is correct. Add a few println(...) statements to make sure the value in your variables are correct.

Comment: My sql statements works perfectly. The problem isn't the JList but the database. It just removes the last object added in the object. While searching I found this discussion. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104882/java-delete-a-selected-row-resultset-deletes-last-row-from-the-database-instea It looks like the person had the same problem as I have right now. But when I try doing like the person is I get this error: Result Set not updatable.This result set must come from a statement that was created with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE